# Import SSL certificate by certutil in InstallShield

Tags: installshield, installscript, certutil

I have a function as below :

```
function LONG ImportSSL(hMSI)    
    STRING exeDir;  
    STRING sslDir; 
    NUMBER nvSize; 
    LONG ret;
begin     
    nvSize = 256; 
    MsiGetProperty (hMSI, "SETUPEXEDIR", exeDir, nvSize);    
    sslDir  = exeDir ^ "ssl\\myCertificate.pfx";
    ret = LaunchAppAndWait(WINDIR, "certutil -f -p \"\"  -importpfx \"" + sslDir + "\"", WAIT);
    if (ret != 0) then return ret; endif; 

    return 0; 
end;
```

by running `Setup.exe` as below:

`MySetup.exe  /v"/l*v c:\SetupLog.log"`

I see the below error in log file :

> CustomAction ImportSSL returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
>   Action ended 16:25:25: ImportSSL. Return value 3.

**but when I execute `certutil -f -p ""  -importpfx "C:\myCertificate.pfx"` by command prompt there is no any error , and that certeficate imported into IIS.**

How can I know the details of error?

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: SprintfMsiLog - Give yourself some information to work with. Check built paths, return codes, whatever helps you identify what's amiss.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solution will depend on the following: 1)Is certificate file being delivered by the installer, or is it supposed to be present on the target machine? Check that the installer delivers it as a permanent file, or support file (in [SUPPORTDIR]), or if the file really exists; 2) where this custom action is located? Normally actions like that should be placed after InstallFinalize.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have added that certificate file in Support Files in Disk1 so it is located in `Setup.exe` dir, but about that action I also defined an action in InstallScript under Behavior and Logic, and made a related custom action mapped to that main action in InstallScript at the end in User Interface Sequence it will be executed after all actions.